# how to pass mysql_insert_id() to either $_POST or form action?

Tags: php, mysql-insert-id

I have a form page in which either an INSERT or an UPDATE query is submitted, depending on the presence/absence of an ID (and when there's an ID it's used to retrieve the record and pre-populate the form). In either case, the processing is in form.php so the form's action is itself (`action="/form.php">`). My problem is that when form.php reloads post-submit, the URL has an empty ID so the page enters 'INSERT' mode, rather than 'UPDATE' mode. What's the best practice way to resolve this?

1. What operator/condition should I add to this 'if' ...

   `if (isset($_GET['ID']) && is_numeric($_GET['ID'])) {`

... to include post-submit empty ID URL (i.e., `form.php?ID=`)

OR,

1. How do I pass `$newID = mysql_insert_id();1 to the form's action? (I've tried a number of variations here w/out success)

   `$newID = mysql_insert_id();`
   ... [ snip ] ...
   `<form method="post" action="/html/form.php?ID=<?php echo $newID; ?>">`

I'm reading about hidden inputs and sessions but it's not yet clear to me how to use either to solve this problem. Lastly, since it isn't absolutely necessary that I reload the form page, I'm increasingly tempted to move the form processing/db queries to another page (e.g., process.php) to hopefully simplify; any opinions on this? What's best/common practice?

Many thanks in advance,

svs

Comment: Thanks Rikudo. I've revisited some of my prev posts and updated where possible.

Comment: Otherwise, why the down-vote? Is my question not legit/useful?

Comment: p.s. Thanks for the repair Marshall. (took me a few tries to add this comment)

Comment: Don't know, I didn't down voted it, upvoted it though to balance. Question is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice should be to keep data posting separate from data displaying.  This prevents accidental adds on a user's first arrival to the page as well as accidental double-posts if the user hits refresh.

In addition, keeping the logic separate makes the code more readable and maintainable in the future.

The approach you should probably look for is:

```
view.php?ID=<record to view> // Only displays a record already in the DB
add.php                      // The add record form with action="process_add.php"
process_add.php?Field1=<>&Field2=<>... // Receives data from add.php, puts it in
                                       // the database and then forwards back to
                                       // view.php or add.php as you see fit.
```

**EDIT**: While I have GET arguments on process_add.php, they are only there to demonstrate that they are being passed.  They should be sent as POST arguments in and actual implementation.

Comment: Thank you tdk001. In fact I originally had a separate process.php when form.php was simpler than it is now, so I'll get on with moving the INSERT & UPDATE queries back. Still, I'll have to pass mysql_insert_id to form.php from process.php, so post-submit, I'll always be in EDIT mode of the last-edited/created record. Cheers

Comment: GET method shouldn't be used for storing data.

Comment: Thx Col. I'm using GET because I'm sometimes getting to form.php from a summary view page (all records) using an 'Edit Record' link; otherwise I get to form.php from a 'New Record' link.

Comment: I think @Col.Shrapnel was meaning for the processing page, and he's right.  `GET` is okay to go to `view.php` or `add.php` in my example above, but you should use `POST` when going from `add.php` to `process_add.php`.

Comment: ah yes, I got that (no pun intended ;) ... I'm using $_POST when submitting the form

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of such a code, using templates.
working CRUD application based on the idea of passing id

dunno, though, why do you need to pass freshly generated id.

```
<?  
mysql_connect(); 
mysql_select_db("new"); 
$table = "test"; 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { //form handler part: 
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
  if ($id = intval($_POST['id'])) { 
    $query="UPDATE $table SET name='$name' WHERE id=$id"; 
  } else { 
    $query="INSERT INTO $table SET name='$name'"; 
  } 
  mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query); 
  header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);  
  exit;  
}  
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) { //listing part: 
  $LIST=array(); 
  $query="SELECT * FROM $table";  
  $res=mysql_query($query); 
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) $LIST[]=$row; 
  include 'list.php'; 
} else { // form displaying part: 
  if ($id=intval($_GET['id'])) { 
    $query="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id=$id";  
    $res=mysql_query($query); 
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) $row[$k]=htmlspecialchars($v); 
  } else { 
    $row['name']=''; 
    $row['id']=0; 
  } 
  include 'form.php'; 
}  
?>
```

templates:
form.php

```
<? include TPL_TOP ?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$row['name']?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
<input type="submit"><br>
<a href="?">Return to the list</a>
</form>
<? include TPL_BOTTOM ?>
```

and list.php:

```
<? include TPL_TOP ?>
<a href="?id=0">Add item</a>
<? foreach ($LIST as $row): ?>
<li><a href="?id=<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['name']?></a>
<? endforeach ?>
<? include TPL_BOTTOM ?>
```

Comment: Cheers, Col. Much to digest here. At this point, since I'm likely to remove the processing from form.php, I haven't yet figured what I'll want to do post-submit, so I might not have to pass mysql_insert_id after all. I.e., I might just return to the summary view, from which, as I noted above, I can either edit an existing record or fire up a new one.

Comment: Thanks again Col. Definitely some syntax in your code I can learn from and improve on my work to date.

Comment: Glad you like it. I believe you can get some ideas too, like using templates or 3-way using id, when it's unset, zero or pozitie